# I am using algebraic option but why must I specify some constants that are only needed for expressions written in RPN?

Tags: pstricks

Please consider `\pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}` in the following code snippet.

```
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \edef\next{round(#3}%
        \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\next:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}
```

Its purpose is to define a constant for expressions written in RPN notation.

My complete code below

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \edef\next{round(#3}%
        \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\next:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}


\const{Vox}{2}
\const{Xo}{1}

\const{Voy}{4}
\const{Yo}{10}

\const{G}{10}

\def\X(#1){Xo+Vox*#1}
\def\Y(#1){Yo+Voy*#1-0.5*G*#1^2}

\const{Tp}{Voy/G}
\const{Toffset}{0.5}


\const{Tf}{2*Tp+Toffset}

\const{Xp}{\X(Tp)}
\const{Yp}{\Y(Tp)}
\const{Xf}{\X(Tf)}
\const{Yf}{\Y(Tf)}

\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,\Yp)(\Xf,\Yf)
    \psframe*[linecolor=lightgray](0,\Yf)(\Xo,\Yo)
    \psparametricplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]{0}{\Tf}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
    \rput[B]{45}(\Xp,\Yp){\bomb}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

use `\psparametricplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]{0}{\Tf}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}` with `algebraic` option. As you can see there is no expressions written in RPN notation.

However, if I disable `\pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}` (by commenting it with `%`), the compilation successes in `latex` and `dvips` phases but fails in `ps2pdf` phase with

```
Error: /undefined in Xo
... <other errors go here but omitted for brevity> ....
```

I am using `algebraic` option but why must I specify some constants that are only needed for expressions written in RPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to define constants in PS world if I change the parametric function with constants from TeX world.

```
\def\X(#1){\Xo+\Vox*#1}
\def\Y(#1){\Yo+\Voy*#1-0.5*\G*#1^2}
```

Comment: I just realized this several minutes ago by accident. Oh my ghost!